# json_encode adding lots of decimal digits

Tags: php

Why is this happening? Can I prevent this? (besides passing them as string)

```
var_dump(json_encode([1002.31, 2002.42]));
```

outputs:

```
string(39) "[1002.3099999999999,2002.4200000000001]"
```

Comment: because floating point. there is no *exact* binary representation of 1002.31, so internally PHP uses the the closest one, which is 1002.30999....... see also: **[the floating-point guide](http://floating-point-gui.de/)**

Comment: You are concerned about the wrong issue here. Decode the JSON and check if the values are decoded correctly. If they are then everything works fine. Stop worrying about the JSON; it is just an intermediate.

Comment: You cannot work with floats and expect any particular accuracy at any one point. Floats are always going to be *approximate values*.

Comment: The problem is that it adds a lot of useless bytes in the API response

Comment: Is your response so large that this makes a huge difference? Even if you return thousands of values, gzipping the response should make that difference mostly negligible. There are three things to worry about: 1) the type of the value (float or string), 2) the accuracy of the value, 3) the size of the response. Pick which one is the most important aspect and mitigate the other two points using other techniques (e.g. gzip).

Comment: @the_nuts and the solution is transparent compression

Comment: or using a regex :) (I know it is very bad practice) http://i.imgur.com/DUU3hvV.png

Comment: What version of php do you use?

Comment: @ValeryViktorovsky 7.1.1

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should configure '[precision](http://php.net/precision)' and 'serialize_precision' params.

```
precision = 14
serialize_precision = -1
```

Test case:

```
php -r 'var_dump(json_encode([1002.31, 2002.42]));'
string(39) "[1002.3099999999999,2002.4200000000001]"

php -r 'ini_set("precision", 14); ini_set("serialize_precision", -1); var_dump(json_encode([1002.31, 2002.42]));'
string(17) "[1002.31,2002.42]"
```

Comment: This is THE solution (`serialize_precision`, `precision` was already at 14). I should update my php.ini since I read that -1 is the default from php 7.1

Comment: Add this to the top of code `ini_set('serialize_precision','-1');` to stop this behaviour - tested on PHP 7.2

Answer (score 5):

**Quick solution** from me. Add this line to your PHP code.

```
ini_set('serialize_precision','-1');
```

Answer (score 4):

This is occurring due to the inaccuracy of floating points as they cannot be directly represented in binary.
A site that explains some of this [is here](http://floating-point-gui.de/).

A quick fix may be to pass them through as strings and convert them back at the other end, or multiply them up to be integers and then again convert back at the other end.

Sadly there is no real 'fix' for this behaviour.

Comment: Yeah I was hoping at something like `ini_set('precision', 2)` but I can't find anything... The only solution would be making a custom json_encode function, but I don't think it's worth...

Comment: Yeah there isn't anything like that that I'm aware of. I guess you could write a custom function but you'd probably be mad to do that. Multiplying up/down might be easiest for you if data type is important. If not then string is still the easiest method.