# Unexpected behavior in PHP when serializing to JSON

Tags: php, json, laravel

PHP 7.3.15
LARAVEL 5.8.38

```
dump(ini_get('serialize_precision'));
// Out: "-1"

$data = DB::table('SOME QUERY HERE')->get();
dump($data);
 #items: array:10 [
    0 => {#713
      +"creation": "2020-04-23 04:00:00"
      +"user_name": "Some Client"
      +"amount": 17.8
      +"count": 3
    }

dump(json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
[
    {
        "creation": "2020-04-23 04:00:00",
        "user_name": "Some Client",
        "amount": 17.799999999999997 // Why?
        "count": 3
    }
```

What am I doing wrong here?
I need the same precision here when I send the data in JSON to my Javascript client.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**
I was already doing this:

```
ini_set("serialize_precision", -1);
```

But this works:

```
dump(json_encode([1002.31, 2002.42]));
// Out: "[1002.31,2002.42]"
```

Seems the problem is when serializing Laravel collections?

Comment: _What am I doing wrong here?_ We don't know as you actually don't show us what your code  is doing between the 2 steps

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41824959/json-encode-adding-lots-of-decimal-digits is maybe helpful, a PHP setting

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43056278/7440243 should solve your precision problem. side note do some more research next time.

Comment: I updated the questions, thanks for commenting

Comment: Don't store money as floats because _this exact reason_.

Comment: @Sammitch A better way is to use integers and save in cents?